# Julia - Platform specific file paths

Tags: path, julia

Whats the most clever (or preferably the right way) to handle different file system paths?

i.e

**Windows**

```
cd("Folder\\\\file.jl") #this becomes "\\"
```

**Unix**

```
cd("Folder/file.jl")
```

The only solution that comes to mind is declairing a global variable at runtime

```
@windows_only global slash = "\\"
@linux_only global slash = "/"
```

but that looks awfully dodgy

Comment: `joinpath("folder","file")` is your friend.

Comment: thanks! thats what I need

Answer (score 14):

`joinpath("Folder","file.jl")` should do the trick.

From the REPL `?joinpath` gives:

```
joinpath(parts...) -> AbstractString

Join path components into a full path. If some argument is an absolute
path, then prior components are dropped.
```

So, if needed more than two path parts can be joined as in:

`joinpath("dir1","dir2","file1") == "dir1/dir2/file1"` (on a Linux machine)